# How to use more than one ace editor in a single component in ng2-ace-editor

Tags: angular, ace-editor

How can we use the more than one ace editor in angular with in a single component.

I would like to use more than one editor in a single component, like similar below.

```
<div #editor ace-editor [(text)]="text" [mode]="'groovy'" [options]="options" [readOnly]="false" [theme]="'eclipse'" [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)" style="min-height: 300px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"> </div>

<div #editor ace-editor [(text)]="text" [mode]="'groovy'" [options]="options" [readOnly]="false" [theme]="'eclipse'" [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)" style="min-height: 300px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"> </div>
```

We need to use more than one editor instance. How can we do that?

we are Loading Custom string into editor for autocomplete like below. I want to use two different custom strings for two different editor.

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
 var stepLineCompleter = {

 getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
 var completions = [];
 x.forEach(function (w) {
 completions.push({
 value: w,
 meta: y,
 name: y
 });
 });

 callback(null, completions);
 }
 }
 langTools.addCompleter(stepLineCompleter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes and it should work

Change the #editor to any other term like #editor1 and it should work.

```
<div #editor ace-editor [(text)]="text" [mode]="'groovy'" [options]="options" [readOnly]="false" [theme]="'eclipse'" [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)" style="min-height: 300px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"> </div>

<div #editor1 ace-editor [(text)]="text" [mode]="'groovy'" [options]="options" [readOnly]="false" [theme]="'eclipse'" [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)" style="min-height: 300px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"> </div>
```

You can also check the stackblitz example on the link below :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ace-code-editor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for ur information...We are not using view child.... We are using only the options.. While loading the custom strings for auto complete it is reflecting in another editor also. Example If I loading any custom strings in editor but it also showing editor1.   I have added the code in my question. Please check

Comment: Hey Vicky, could you please let me know where is your code, as i can't see the code on the StackBlitz link, please help me with the code so that I can review and get back to you.

Comment: I didn't create StackBlitz link, can u please see my question above.  I have added the string completer using language tools. I want to do it for two different editor in a single component.